# Is limit of composite function applicable when the function depends on $n$?

Tags: calculus

I know limit of composite function rule from https://teachingcalculus.com/2019/08/26/limit-of-composite-functions/.

However, is it still possible to compute the following like this? The function itself depends on $n$, so I'm not sure function and limit can be interchanged in this case.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac 1n(t^2+t^3/\sqrt n +t^4/\sqrt {n^3}+ ...)\right)^n=
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac 1nt^2\right)^n=\exp(t^2)$$

Comment: If that were valid, you could equally well say $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac 1n(t^2+t^3/\sqrt n +t^4/\sqrt {n^3}+ ...)\right)^n=
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1\right)^n=1,$$ right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Greg Martin, generally you cannot but asymptotics can be useful to guess the answer and then prove it rigorously. As is the case here, the limit is indeed $\exp(t^2)$

Notice that,

$$\left(1+\frac 1n(t^2+t^3/\sqrt n +t^4/\sqrt {n^3}+ ...)\right)^n=\exp\left[n\ln\left(1+\frac 1n(t^2+t^3/\sqrt n +t^4/\sqrt {n^3}+ ...)\right)\right]$$

Since $\exp$ is continuous, the limit equals the $\exp$ of the limit of the inside expression as $n\to\infty$. Now,

$$n\ln\left(1+\frac 1n(t^2+t^3/\sqrt n +t^4/\sqrt {n^3}+ ...)\right)=\frac{\ln(1+t^2/n+t^3/n^{3/2}+t^4/n^{5/2}+\ldots)}{1/n}$$

after which you can use L'Hopital once and see this goes to $t^2$ as $n\to\infty$ and hence the original limit is $\exp(t^2)$

Comment: You don't have to explicitly write out the terms after the l'hopital; just note that it gives $\dfrac{t^2+\text{terms with positive finite power of $n$ in denominator}}{1+\text{terms with positive finite power of $n$ in denominator}}$ and these latter terms all tend to $0$ as $n\to\infty$

Comment: Great! Thanks for your clear answer!